# How MCA user id authorizes a client user id using MQ Server connection channels

Tags: client, ibm-mq

I have a question on how the MCA user id we add while creating a WebSphere MQ Server Connection channel actually authorizes a client user id configured in an MQ client Application.
For e.g I have a domain user account servicemq01@domain added as MCA user id for a Server connection channel APP1.SVRCONN.01. I have created a user group mqi_App1@server and added the servicemq01@domain user id into it. The mqi_App1 group is given required authorities to connect to the queue manager. Also the required authorities are added at the queue level for mqi_App1 group.

Now the client Application App1 has a userid clientapp01@domain with which it runs. The client Application is trying to connect to MQ server using channel APP1.SVRCONN.01.  My question is does both the clientapp01@domain and servicemq01@domain needs to match for the MQ Server connection channel to work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  By putting a UserId in the channel's MCAUSER field, you are overriding the UserId that the application is using.  Any and ALL applications that connect on channel 'APP1.SVRCONN.01' will be using UserId 'servicemq01@domain'.

Very trusting of you and not very secure.